# Listview dynamically add and remove items not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Guys i am going crazy here. Pls i have a listview which i want to dynamically i add an item from a textbox into the list on button click. I want to remove on button click as well. My problem is i currently couldn't add a single item in to the listview because i am gtetting error.I want to my listview to have two columns and therefore insert two strings of data in an array as follows

```
  string[] array = { DropDownListType.SelectedItem.Text, txtDescription.Text };

            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add(array[0]);
            foreach(string[] value in list)
            {

                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(value);

                       ListViewDesc.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
```

Previously, i added my strings from array without the list but all failed. I i am really confused. Moreover the property "`Listview.Column.Add`" gives not known property error. Please any alternative way i can achieve this would be appreciated.i Have my listview below.

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListViewDesc" runat="server">
               </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423537/how-to-add-subitems-to-a-listview

Answer (score 1):

your foreach is trying to use a array but "list" is a list of strings try

```
 string[] array = { DropDownListType.SelectedItem.Text, txtDescription.Text };

        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add(array[0]);
        foreach(var value in list)
        {

            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(value);

                   ListViewDesc.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
```

also look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.grouptemplate.aspx

and unless you HAVE to I would not use a listview. A table is better I think

Answer (score 0):

Use databinding instead:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var list = new List<ItemsInList>
                   {
                       new ItemsInList { Text = "Testtext1" },
                       new ItemsInList { Text = "Testtext2" },
                   };

        ListViewDesc.DataSource = list;
        ListViewDesc.DataBind();
    }
}

public class ItemsInList
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}


        <asp:ListView ID="ListViewDesc" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <p>
                    <%# Eval("Text") %>
                </p>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```